# Removing specific special characters from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I would like to remove spaces(' '), dots('.') and hyphens(-) from a string, using a regular expression.

My current approach:

```
string input = "hello     how --r dsbadb...dasjidhdsa.dasbhdgsa--dasb";          
var res = input
     .ToCharArray()
     .Where(i => i != ' ' && i != '-' && i != '.')
     .Aggregate(" ", (a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string filteredInput = Regex.Replace(input, "[ .-]+", "");
```

should be easier and more readable.

Comment: try `input = Regex.Replace` ..(etc) - it creates a new string instead of changing it "in place"

Comment: I suggest you use `[ .-]+` so adjacent characters are replaced at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = string.Concat(input.Where(c => !new[] { '.', ' ', '-' }.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: @Joey, Provide sample with except.

Comment: @Joey, with except output will be `helowrdsbajigvf`. Test your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[\s\.-]+", "");
```

`\s` would target space, `\.` would target dots, and `-` would target hyphens and will replace them with empty string